# JavaScript firebase real-time Database not working as everything is set correctly

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a web app, i'm trying to upload my data into the **firebase Realtime Database** , but it is not showing up there everything is set correctly, application is working properly, there are no errors!. but the problem is data is not getting updated into the Realtime database.

```
 firebase.database().ref().child("account/" + user.uid).set({
        fname: fname,
        mname: mname,
        lname: lname,
        contact: contact,
        email: email
    })
```

Edit : 2
This is the error but it still doesn't show up in realtime database
[image]

Comment: Can you try adding `.then(() => console.log("Data added")).catch(e => console.log(e))` to `set()` and share a screenshot of error is any ?

Comment: There 's no error again and nothing showed up in realtime